# Gremilin select Id from elementMap to get the vertex by id

Tags: gremlin

I try to get a vertex by an id which is in a element map. Something like

```
g.V(g.V().limit(1).elementMap().as(‘map’).select(‘map’).by(‘id’))
```

This is just a simplified example I must use the elementMap since I get an elementMap from an union result where I must use elementMap to order the vertices by specific properties which might be not available in a vertex.

And what I don’t understand at all is why selecting id or label returns null, while selecting an other property from the map of the vertex works.

```
g.V().limit(1).elementMap().as(‘map’).select(‘map’).by(‘id’)
==>null
g.V().limit(1).elementMap().as(‘map’).select(‘map’).by(‘key’)
==>value
```

So how can I achieve selecting the id in the elementMap to get the vertex for that id?

Answer (score 0):

```
gremlin> g.V(    
  g.V().limit(1).elementMap().unfold()   
    .where(select(keys).is(eq(id))).select(values).next() )
==>v[1]
```

Things got confusing because your original query had three issues:

1. You have to next() the inner traversal to get a value rather than the value wrapped in an iterating GraphTraversal. Note that the gremlin console does next() automatically for the outer traversal.
2. The by() modulator on the elementMap only works on the values of the Map
3. Although the ElementMap seems to show an 'id' string as key it actually is the id token defined by TinkerPop

Finally note that you may not need the elementMap step at all and do the query like this:

```
gremlin> g.V(g.V().limit(1).id().next())
==>v[1]
```

[This answer was significantly extended after the comments below]

Comment: As I wrote, I must get the id from the elementMap.

Comment: As you see you from my example, you have to next() the inner traversal to get an identifier from the GraphTraversal iterator. Please try it in your own query.

Comment: Its not working. g.V(g.V().limit(1).elementMap().id().next()) doesn’t work neither as expected. As I wrote it’s a map I am working on and not a traversal.